# ADC interface to MCU

Tags: microcontroller, adc, interface

I have been looking at the ADC ADC12010CIVYX/NOPB 12bit 10MSPS,
(https://www.mouser.in/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/ADC12010CIVYX-NOPB?qs=7X5t%252BdzoRHATGLGld5L%2FWA%3D%3D), with a parallel interface
for RF sampling purposes. I an not aware how to interface it with an MCU. I know that there exists DSPs with parallel interface which can be used with this ADC. But I wanted to interface it with an ARM MCU (just for consideration i.MX RT600) so that I can execute certain signal processing as well.

Comment: You can connect the 12 data bits to gpio and the clk to a timer output. You would need to read the datasheet to see if the dma controller can read from gpio. If not, then look for another solution.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you'll need something with a parallel interface that's sufficiently fast.

If your MCU doesn't have that, your only choice would be to use an external method of converting that parallel bus to a serial one (typically: an FPGA, CPLD or just a parallel-in, serial out shift register), but the truth is that high-speed ADCs have data rates who will, serialized to a serial one bit bus, be higher than what your MCU offers.

So, the answer is: if your MCU has no parallel port, and none of the "simple" serial ports (SPI) offers bit rates sufficiently high for your ADC's bit rate 120 Mb/s, then you simply **cannot connect the ADC to your MCU**. 120 Mb/s is beyond any SPI bus I saw.

This is a common problem, and it turns out that you almost always end up doing this with either a specialized DSP or some FPGA as the element that does the signal processing. Sometimes, an FPGA is used to buffer and protocol-handle things, so that you can connect the ADC to a non-deterministic-timing bus like PCIe, Gigabit Ethernet or even USB, for which some microcontrollers have sufficiently fast interfaces.

So, nope, unless your MCU has a parallel bus you forgot to mention, directly connecting your ADC to your MCU doesn't work. It will also often be unable to supply sample and data clocks to your ADC, either. So, really, you're stuck with an FPGA.